# Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight Prerequisites & other algebra book recommendations

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm going to start Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight soon, but I would like to know if there are any prerequisites to this book.

My goal is to obtain a solid foundation of algebra; more specifically, a foundation necessary to learn calculus, which is what I plan to learn. The book I will use to learn calculus is called *Calculus*, by Michael Spivak.

I have rather basic algebra skills (only high school math), and my mathematical maturity is quite low, so I'm trying to build my "math muscles" until I'm ready to tackle calculus. If *Higher Algebra* is too rigorous for my current math level, I would like to receive any book recommendations for mathematical texts that might suit me better.

Comment: Its a pretty old book, how did you come to it ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I ended up finding out that it was a good book for algebra preparation for the IIT JEE exam.